# No SSL or TLS certificate for MQ Channel (Running from terminal - Windows 10)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, keystore

I am trying to connect to a remote MQ on the company I work, using the following command, which comes after installing the MQ Client (`IBM MQ version 9.04.0`) on my machine,

Input:

```
P:\>amqssslc -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256CBC_SHA256 -k "t:\Desktop\certificates\key" -x "server.com(1414)" -c "0000%XXXX%QMGR" -m QMGR
```

Output:

```
Sample AMQSSSLC start Connecting to queue manager
Using the server connection channel 0000%XXXX%QMGR
on connection name server.com(1414).
Using SSL CipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256CBC_SHA256
Using SSL key repository stem t:\Desktop\certificates\key
No OCSP configuration specified
MQCONNX ended ith reason code 2393
```

Where the `-k` indicates the key.* path, which is a group of files (kdb, rdb, sht). These files were created using `IKeyMan - IBM Key Manager` from a `cer.jks` file that current developers use to connect on a web app.

The error log file shows the following error:

```
06/11/202020 19:29:45 - Process(25780.1) User(username) Program(amqssslc.exe)
                      Host(myhost) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.1.3.0)
                      Time(2020-06-11T09:24:53.270Z)
                      RemoteHost(xx.xx.xxx.56)
                      CommenInsert1(0000%XXXX%QMGR)
                      CommenInsert2(server.com(1414))

AMQ9642: No SSL or TLS certificate for channel '0000%XXXX%QMGR'.

EXPLANATION:
The channel '0000%XXXX%QMGR' did not supply a certificate to use during SSL
or TLS handshaking, but a certificate is required by the remote queue manager. 

The remote host is 'server.com(1414)'. 

The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository of the local queue manager or MQ client contains
a certificate which is associated with the queue manager or client.
Alternatively, if appropriate, change the remote channel definition so that its
SSLCAUTH attribute is set to OPTIONAL and it has no SSLPEER value set.
```

Where it leads me to believe that the error is related to the handshake on the channel side. **Jks certificate works for the other developers who make the connection to the queue on the server.**

My mqclient.ini file has the following added configuration:

```
TCP:
    KeepAlive = Yes

CLientExithPath: 
    ExitsDefaultPath=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\exits
    ExitsDefaultPath64=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\exits64

SSL: 
    OCSPAuthentication=NO
    OCSPCheckExtension=NO
    CDPCheckExtension=NO
```

What could be the issue? I have also tried changing the **label of my certificate** to indicate a personal certificate there is on the key.kdb file, however, it drops a different error, what I was told from the IT guys at the company I work, is that this certificate label is not needed.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the quick suggestions. The version is 9.1.3.0, we have different machines, I reran everything with this current version. When running with -l to indicate the personal certificate (which was also shown as you mentioned by running `runmqakm` containing the `-`) It returned exactly the same error. I converted the `jks` to `kdb` using IBM Key management GUI. By first opening the jks and then `saving as`  kdb. Is this step wrong? @JoshMC

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the cipher and re-run the command using the certificate label with `-l` and this is the error I get now, `MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035`

Comment: That is a security error but you are making it past tls negotiation.

Comment: Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: The best places to check is the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` file.

Comment: Error `MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035` does not log anything on the `AMQERR01.LOG` file. What exactly did you mean by saying that I am making it past tls negotiation. And also going back to the question where I told you how I converted from `jks` to `kdb`, did that seem correct to you?

Comment: I have never used the gui, but sounds right.  What version is the queue manager running

Comment: 2035 could be a permission issue.  It could mean that your client user does not exist on the queue manager.  It could mean the queue manager requires you send a valid user and password..

Comment: That is what I have read. Do you think is related to not having admin rights as well? Could this be a potential issue? Else I will also look at the error log files from the qmgr

Comment: 2035 comes from the server and is post TLS negotiation.

Comment: Hey Josh, yes it worked in the end. The problem was that my user was not authorized on the channel. It worked only after my user was allowed to connect

Comment: Edgar, I think with my help you did figure out the original 2393 error and I have posted a answer with those details, would you please accept it and upvote if this was helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the OP (@EdgarHernandez) noticed the error was a typo in the CipherSpec, `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256CBC_SHA256` instead of the correct name `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` was causing/contributing to the 2393

Putting my troubleshooting notes from the comments in this answer for so they are searchable for future SO users looking at similar errors.

---

There is a difference in how Java/JMS selects a cert to send to the queue manager and how a client using the C libraries selects the cert to send to the queue manager.

### Java/JMS:

Java does not use cert label, it provides a cert that it thinks is a match to present to the queue manager based on what issuers that queue manager trusts, so it is good enough to have the a personal cert that is issued by a CA that the queue manager trusts.

### C library client:

C library clients (which `amqssslc` is) bases cert selection this on the cert label. By default it will look for a label `ibmwebspheremq<lowercase username>`, so if you run as a user `edgar` the cert the MQ client will look for is `ibmwebspheremqedgar`

- In MQ v8.0 and later you can specify a alternate label than the default value. `amqssslc` does this with the `-l` label option. So if your cert was labeled just `edgar`, you should be able to add `-l edgar` to pick up the cert.

---

Use the following command to check that you have a personal cert listed, it should be prefixed with a `-` in the first column, if it is only prefixed with a `!` then it is only the public portion of the key, not the private.

`runmqakm -cert -list -db t:\Desktop\certificates\key.kdb -stashed`